# How to add new row on table Angular 11?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to make a table that I can add new row or delete the existing row. But the table is not getting any data from data source, or interface, or anything. I need to insert an input on the table. Here's the picture of the table
[image: Table]

In that picture I already make the UI, but I don't know how to add new row on that table using the add button, or delete the existing row using the existing row.

Here's the code I'm using so far

**HTML**

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Path</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of dataSources">
            <td><input class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid" type="text"></td>
            <td><input class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid" type="text"></td>
            <td>
                <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" (click)="addNewRow()">
                    <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
                </button> |
                <button mat-mini-fab color="warn" (click)="deleteRow()">
                    <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**TS**

```
addNewRow() {
    console.log('NEW ROW CREATED!');   }

  deleteRow() {
    console.log('ROW HAS BEEN DELETED!');   }
```

I need to make the add button and the delete button works properly. Any idea how to do this? Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: you havent put and logic inside the addNewRow and deleteRow methods? There are just consoles.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @WahabShah I know, and that's the problem. I don't know the logic to make it work.

Comment: Okay. So there is a form on in which you will add data and it will go inside the table as a row or the image that you have shared every row needs to have an add and delete button?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you're looking to add a row that contains a FormControl.
This might be possible to achieve but I strongly recommand to use a FormArray instead.

It will be far easier to manage your FormControls as an array than process them individually

Have a look at this comprehensive guide:
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-form-array/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).